# cannot read tagName of undefined on dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I'm using jsPanel with jQuery and I continue to run into a problem. Whenever I try to click a link to open a panel I get a console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined"

Below is my code.

```
    $('#deviceList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkAdminDevice', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $( '#option-ajax' ).jsPanel({
        size : "auto",
        theme: "info",
        overflow: 'hidden',
        contentBG: {'padding': '20px' },
        ajax: {
            url: 'admindevice/' + id
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Post the HTML code too, you're probably referring to a non existing object.

Comment: I think the problem is the majority of the content is loaded with ajax

Comment: So how would one attach an event listener to content loaded with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

To what element do want to append the jsPanel to? It seems to me that you try to append the jsPanel to an element that does not exist.

In your example code you try to append a jsPanel to an element with an id of **option-ajax**. Does this element exist in your page? You probably get the TypeError because the script wants to read the tagName of the element you want to append the jsPanel to. And if the element is not present than there is no tagName to read.

```
$( selector ).jsPanel( { options }, callback );
```

A jsPanel will always be appended to the **first** element specified by the jQuery selector expression.

I hope that helped.